# EOFError in Shortcut Script: (raw) Keyboad-Input in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, input, keyboard-shortcuts, raw-input

My first Python script should be a Keyboard-Shortcut-Quiz:

As a lot of Keyboard Shortcuts only work in combination with CTRL, SHIFT or WIN/OS Key the most "answers" of the quiz will contain on of those "system-keys".

Unfortunately this System Keys are leading to "EOFError: EOF when reading a line".

```
answer = str(input("How do you switch to the Desktop?"))

if answer in ['^D']:
    print("Right!")
```

I tested it with `['D']` instead of `['^D']` and the script worked fine.
Its clear that the `^` which stands for CTRL is the reason for the error.

Now I am asking myself on how to read RAW keyboard shortcuts combinations properly in python.
(I know that `raw_input` is just `input` now with Python 3.)

PS: I didnt came across a solution on how to read the input of the WIN Key properly, is this even possible?

Answer (score 0):

Using the method you're using, you can't take the input of ctrl and parse it to be readable by python unless you use AHK([AutoHotKey](https://pypi.org/project/ahk/)). I highly recommend you try it out, it takes inputs such as 'ctrl' and you can 'mash it together' the way you need to use it. I'm sorry I couldn't offer much more than this, but it seems like the most viable alternative!

Comment: Do you mean I should put "pyahk" within my little project or whats the best way to implement AutoHotKey in Python? Thanks for helping me with this niche question :)